# difference between vector<thread> and vector<thread *>

Tags: c++, multithreading, pointers

Question about threads in C++

What are the advantages and disadvantages of using  one or the other ?

```cpp
vector<thread> tvec;
...
```

or

```cpp
vector<thread*> tvec; // or vector<shared_ptr<thread>> tvec;
...
```

Comment: do you know the difference between `std::vector<int>` and `std::vector<int*>` ?

Comment: yes the problem is not about whet is a pointer but I want to know if there is a difference with the threads

Comment: @cmdEvo: The difference is one stores the object directly, the other through a pointer. Are you expecting a difference beyond that? Threads aren't special here, only behavior difference is you could copy the pointer-based `vector` but not the plain object one (`thread` isn't copyable).

Comment: the question is unclear and too broad. I could also have asked: Do you know the difference between a `thread` and a `thread*` ? You are mixing many things that are somewhat orthogonal, a pointer does not care that much whether it is in side a container or not. Dynamic memory allocation is difficult, whether its a `thread` or something else

Comment: the second one is more bug prone.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`std::thread` is a tiny class containing mostly just the thread ID or handle. It is also movable, and so is a good candidate to be stored in a `vector` by-value.

So it's easiest and most readable to store them by-value, as it `vector<thread> tvec;`.

In addition, the form `vector<T*>` carries non-owning semantics, and so is probably something different from what you meant to have.

Answer (score 0):

Let's call them value and pointer versions:

1. The value version will have better cache locality for sequential access. If thread is std::thread it would be moveable, otherwise copy constructing is more expensive.
2. The pointer version implies that you always chase a pointer to access it. Page faults are expensive. You can set an entry to a nullptr if an element is optional/missing.  If you use a straight pointer like this you might need to manage resources manually.  This is error prune and leads to resource leaks (in this case threads and memory).

Comment: "each value will be copy constructed [...]" - standard threads are uncopyable.

Comment: I don't think cache locality is that relevant for a container of `thread`. The `thread`s arent that big in memory and most certainly have internal indirection anyhow

Comment: If you get a page fault per access that would be significant.  It's small so maybe they will all be allocated on the same page anyhow.

Comment: do the pointers interfer with the Function && operator ?

Comment: @cmdEvo I am pressing F1 for the crowd smarter than me to chip in.

Answer (score 0):

> difference between `vector<thread>` and `vector<thread *>`

I assume that by `vector`, you mean `std::vector` and by `thread`, you mean `std::thread`. Correct me if I assumed wrongly.

First is a vector that contain `thread` objects. The other is a vector that contains `thread*` objects which are pointers to `thread`.

> What are the advantages and disadvantages of using one or the other ?

Advantage of `vector<thread>` is that you get `thread` objects.
Disadvantage of `vector<thread>` is that you don't get `thread*` objects.

Advantage of `vector<thread *>` is that you get `thread*` objects.
Disadvantage of `vector<thread *>` is that you don't get `thread` objects.

---

`vector<thread>` is useful when you want to start multiple threads for some parallel programming.

I haven't yet encountered a use case where `vector<thread *>` would be useful.